# How do I disable the tiles happening in leaflet? I just want my image to show fit to window and zoom single image

Tags: leaflet

Leaflet framework seems like perfect solution, however it is using tiles to zoom. I want to source a single file and have it fit to window and zoom based on image being much larger than container.

I cannot find anywhere to disable tile feature. If I did would it break zoom functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Sounds like you overlooked Leaflet [Image Overlay](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#imageoverlay).

There is also a [tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html), although you may not need the CRS.Simple part.

Comment: Thank you this example helped me and I have both things working now. I had found something with the image to show but it broke the tooltip. Your example had both so I started over and have it working:) Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Thank you for your feedback. Please also consider marking an answer as _accepted_ if it helped you solve your issue, so that people know your problem is fixed.

Comment: Sounds like you should rather open a new question with description and code for your new issue.